# ¿Cómo convertir fechas integer a fechas Timestamp en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Tengo tabla que contiene fechas en formato integer, o sea, por ejemplo `Octubre 16, 2015` está representado como `41927`. He intentado cambiar el tipo de columna de integer a timestamp y todas las fechas se han hecho `0000-00-00 00:00:00`´...

**¿cómo cambiar correctamente formato de fecha integer a normal Timestamp tipo `2015-10-16 00:00:00` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función FROM_UNIXTIME:

```
 UPDATE `tabla` SET `date_column_timestamp` = FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_column_int`);
```

Aquí puedes ver la documentación de la función:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

Comment: Lo he intentado ya y me da todos los valores = `1970-01-01 12:47:20` con segundos de diferencia....

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "con segundos de diferencia..."?

Comment: He respondido a tu comentario en mi pregunta para que entiendas mejor.

Comment: @Lukas ¿Puedes añadir los valores originales a la pregunta?

Comment: hecho, he añadido valores a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que el resultado no es correcto? ¿Los valores y resultado que has puesto están en el mismo orden? Si se ejecuta la función sobre los 3 valores distintos que has puesto salen estos resultados: `42660->Thu, 01 Jan 1970 11:51:00 GMT
42674->Thu, 01 Jan 1970 11:51:14 GMT
42650->Thu, 01 Jan 1970 11:50:50 GMT`

Comment: Si, perdona, tienes razón, es correcta tu respuesta. La razón por la que decía eso es porque en la base de datos (en excel) tenía fechas no inferiores a 2016 y me habrán cambiado los valores el programa SQLizer.io ... no sólo han cambiado a integer mis fechas sino que los valores también me los han cambiado. Les he escrito al soporte técnico.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `tabla` SET `date_column_timestamp` = cast(fechaenint as datetime)

Comment: Gracias, pero esto me da error: `#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '42660'`

Comment: Prueba UPDATE tabla SET date_column_timestamp = cast(fechaenint as date), después se puede castear a DateTime

Comment: Lo mismo me da `#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '42660'` ..